# How to do a excel transform like below

Tags: excel, range

Please help me to do this for big data list

This is what available

```
ID  Region  E mail 1    E mail 2    E mail 3
A1   B1      E11           E22       E33
A2   B2      E12           E23       E34
A3   B3      E13           E24       E35
```

This is what I need

```
ID  Region  E mail 1    E mail 2    E mail 3

A1   B1      E11        
             E22        
             E33        
A2   B2      E12        
             E23        
             E34        
A3   B3      E13        
             E24        
             E35
```

A[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lV65t.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to unpivot your first table.

Using the free [Excel Add-In Power Query](https://www.microsoft.com/it-IT/download/details.aspx?id=39379) it is easy and you just have to follow [these steps](https://blogs.office.com/2015/12/15/learn-how-to-unpivot-static-tables-in-excel-2016/).
If you don't want to use Power Query you could follow one of the answers of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/78439/is-it-possible-to-unpivot-or-reverse-pivot-in-excel) on Super User.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks..I found some thing like this..

Sub transpose_in_place()
    Dim rw As Long, cl As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        For rw = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
            For cl = .Cells(rw, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column To 3 Step -1
                If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(rw, cl)) Then
                    .Rows(rw + 1).Insert
                    .Cells(rw + 1, 1) = .Cells(rw, 1).Value2
                    .Cells(rw + 1, 2) = .Cells(rw, cl).Value2
                    .Cells(rw, cl).Clear
                End If
            Next cl
        Next rw
    End With
End Sub